# Displaying UDP Multicast Rawvideo Stream

Tags: opencv, ffmpeg, udp, video-streaming

I stream the webcam with FFmpeg (command line) via UDP as above. On the client side I use Java OpenCV, the capture line; `VideoCapture.open("udp://xx.xx.xx.xx:xx)`. If I sent the stream as **mpegts** (`ffmpeg -f mpegts`), I can display the stream but; if I sent it as **rawvideo** (`ffmpeg -f rawvideo`), I couldn't.

Is there any parameter to set (like CvType) ?

Answer (score 1):

Mpegts has properties that are specifically designed for transmission over a one way losssy transport like UDP, or digital television. It has packets that are repeated every 100ms to tell the reader how to bootstrap decoding, it has start of frame flags (payload unit start indicator), it has a packet counter to detect skipped and out of order packets, and several other important features.

Raw video has none of this. It’s just a bunch of bytes.  If a single packet is lost (including the first packet) the decoder will have no idea where the start and end of frames are, and is unable to reconstruct a stream.

Therefor such a feature is generally not supported in video tools. If you need to send raw video, use TCP not UDP.

Comment: thanks szatmary, the explanation is very useful to me, but I wonder that if I use udp, I can stream the webcam with ``ffmpeg -f avfoundation -i "0"  -pix_fmt yuv420p -f rawvideo -pix_fmt yuv420p udp://@236.0.0.1:2000``` (on Mac) and can capture&display with ```ffplay -f rawvideo -pix_fmt yuv420p -video_size 1280x720 -i udp://236.0.0.1:2000```. My goal is image processing (basic features, adjust brightness, contrast etc.) on the video so I'm trying to display via OpenCV. @szatmary, any other advise for reaching the goal?

Comment: It’s possible in theory, but in practice you will encounter many many problems.